# Autoconf macro to check if gcc-multilib is present (if gcc can compile 32bit code)

Tags: gcc, autotools, autoconf

A C-project uses GCC to produce 32-bit objects. To that end, a user building the project in a 64-bit host machine is required to have multilib enabled (e.g. in Unbuntu, `apt install gcc-multilib`).

What is the proper way for autoconf to check if multilib is enabled?

Comment: It's common to have multiple toolchains installed.  Different versions of gcc, clang, icc, etc.  Any of these could build 32-bit objects with a specific distro package being installed.  A better way to think of the problem would be how to test if the selected toolchain can build 32-bit binaries.

Comment: @TrentP, good idea. Sounds much more effective and elegant.